# How to get the screen resolution which was used at design time?

Tags: vb.net, resolution, screen-resolution

I can get the current screen resolution using the code below; however, I would like to get the screen resolution that was used during the design of the forms. Is there anyway to have that information?

Why do I need this?
I have developed a program to automatically scale the controls and their font sizes based on form's last and current size. When the form size at design time is higher than the current screen resolution, some of the controls get cropped. I understand that this behaviour is a .Net framework limitation where any form size cannot be greater the screen resolution. I can overcome this limitation if I get the screen resolution used at design time.

```
Public Function ScreenResolution() As String
        Dim intX As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
        Dim intY As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
        Return intX & " × " & intY
End Function
```

Comment: There is nothing in the build process that automatically embeds this information anywhere. Does merely building the project change the outcome depending on the resolution of the computer building? For instance, if you simply copy the project files to a different computer, and do not open it up in Visual Studio but instead runs `msbuild` or `dotnet build` depending on project types, does the screen resolution of that computer affect the final build output?

Comment: I have rephrased my question. I guess the proper way of asking my question is "how to get the resolution used at design time"

Comment: Why make this any more complicated than store the design time resolution as a constant you update yourself somewhere?

Comment: @Hursey,
Since this project will be updated by other developers, I am worried that they may use a different screen resolution at their development machine

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscaledimensions?view=net-5.0

Comment: *Since this project will be updated by other developers, I am worried that they may use a different screen resolution at their development machine* - so what does that mean for the end user? The form will jump round all over and do inexplicable resizing based on which developer hit Build? Do it properly; look up the runtime screen res and adjust your form according to what is visible oin the user machine, not the developer's